# wireless ISP for upto 55 users what will be the suitable hardware and server technology?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have to setup a wireless ISP that supports at most 55 users, and the cache server should also cache the video streaming. I need to know what is the suitable hardware and which cache server will be more efficient for my task, and also the users are maximum in 1km radius to my ISP so also want to know the about antenna and other hardware that will be good for this task.

It will be great if some one also define the high and medium performance network design for this

i am thinking to go with bullet2hp and a mikrotik server need suggestions

regards

Comment: What country are you in?, Check rules an regulations as output is certainly limited in the UK, you need licenses etc...

Comment: i am in the zone where this work is encouraged on local basis so no problem with licenses etc.

Comment: And who is going to handle your back haul? Your going to need a top level provider to provide your ISP access to the rest of the Net, even if you just need to lease their physical fiber lines.

Comment: Wow, you guys are being silly. For 55 people all he needs is a comcast business line or such. moon, I think your question is fine, but perhaps this isn't the right place to ask.

Comment: Take a look here. - http://acelere.net/notes/index.html

Comment: Found this. http://www.dslreports.com/faq/wisp Lots of information there. Also this http://www.dslreports.com/forum/wisp Apparently, wisp is a keyword you should look for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab that the OP is really trying to setup a Wireless *network* that supports 55 users and is confusing the terms network and ISP (if I'm wrong say so, I'll remove the post). In that case, what you need is a [Wireless Access Point.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point)

If that is indeed the case, I recommend that you setup some Wireless Access Points around your office. Connect them to your existing wired network. Something like a [Cisco Aironet](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10981/index.html) might be a good thing to look at.

Comment: No, you're confused. He wants to create a wireless network to act as an ISP for a 1km radius. Did you even read it?

Comment: Fair. I missed that bit of the post. I couldn't concieve of an ISP for 55 users. Sounds more like a WAN to me...

Comment: Hey, he tried with what he thought was an answer, as the user may be confused. Most people don't setup homemade ISP's.

Comment: Nate, a homemade ISP for 55 people in a 1km in rural areas does make sense. People who do not live in rural areas don't understand though. EDIT: He is from Pakistan. This make sense even more now.

Comment: thank you guys for your comments and guide line well i am still looking for a cheaper hardware